# How do I look up an email from an IP address?

Tags: email, ip

I realize this can run into all kinds of privacy related stuff but how do I look up an email address from an IP address in code? I want to be able to put this code in my web site. Is there a better way than IP address?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no relationship between E-Mail Addresses and IPs. For example the E-Mail-Address: `test@domain.com`
The Domain `domain.com` has an IP. But the full Address consists also of a Username `test`. This has nothing to do with IP Addresses. So you can't do this.

Comment: Right, I understand there is no direct relationship but I found a few services that are able to look up visitor details (name, email, etc...) based on the the visitor's IP address and there are some that use web footprints. I just want to know how they do it or at least have someone point me in the right direction